# Why does translate3d(…) cause a scrollbar on iframes?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an `<iframe>` with `overflow-x: scroll`. When the content of the iframe has `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)` set, a tiny, fixed scrollbar is shown on the bottom of the iframe, even though there is no content to scroll:

[image: scrollbar example]

Without changing the iframe's style, is there any way to hide this scrollbar?

I can't modify the iframe's style because my application is embedded in another website which is difficult to modify.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wby66opd/

Comment: https://crbug.com/567773

Answer (score 0):

For what it’s worth, this is [fixed](https://crrev.com/55de872c090f19fb64fb5e865a86c97334a4f0f0) in Chrome version 51, stable today.